# MySQL Select Random X Entries - Optimized

Tags: mysql, random

MySQL what's the *best way* to select X random entries (rather than just one) - optimization for heavy use, i.e. on main page of a domain.

Supposedly just blindly using MySQL rand() is going to make this rather scary for large databases - please give me a better optimization answer than that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is use php

look at this article that choose the solution number 3 as  faster

http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/

Solution 3 [PHP]

```
$offset_result = mysql_query( " SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS `offset` FROM `table` ");
$offset_row = mysql_fetch_object( $offset_result );
$offset = $offset_row->offset;
$result = mysql_query( " SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT $offset, 1 " )
```

the
 Solution 4 [SQL] (Second in fast)

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM `table` ) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: That's fast but not really random - only 1st value is random.

Comment: its getting one random result, if you want more u can loop on it

Comment: Trying the 4th MySQL solution in link above - seems random-ish

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with the ids. The id was auto generated but the minimum id was very large with respect to the number of total records. So I made a little changes to make the query more randomized, but a little slower though.

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE id >= (SELECT (FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) + MIN(id)) FROM 'table' ) ORDER BY id LIMIT 10
```